# Rebase branch after GitHub "Squash and merge" onto master

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-squash

Let's say I've developed a feature on `branch1` and sent it out for code review using a GitHub Pull Request. While it's being reviewed, I do some follow-on work on `branch2`.

```
 branch2                   -> D --> E --> F
                          /    
 branch1  -> A --> B --> C
         /
 master M
```

My reviewer loves my work! No changes are required. I merge the pull request for `branch1` using GitHub's [Squash and merge](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits) feature.

After running `git pull` on `master` and deleting `branch1`, I'm left with this situation:

```
 branch2  -> A --> B --> C -> D --> E --> F
         /
 master M --> S
```

To send out a clean-looking PR for `branch2`, I'd like to get my commit tree looking like this:

```
 branch2        -> D' --> E' --> F'
               /
 master M --> S
```

The code at `S` (the commit generated by "Squash and merge" for `branch1`) is identical to `C`, since it's just the squashed version of `A --> B --> C`.

One way to achieve this would be to run a sequence like this on `branch2`:

```
git reset --hard S
git cherry-pick D E F
```

But listing all the commits out this way gets tedious, and this really *feels* like a rebase. `git rebase master` won't work, of course, since commits `A`, `B` and `C` need to disappear.

What's the best way to rebase a branch off a squashed version of one of its ancestor commits?

Comment: IIRC you can cherry pick a range of commits e.g. `cherry-pick D..F`

Comment: @Whymarrh: you can, but then you must name `D^` so as to copy `D` itself. The range notation is akin to a half-open interval, excluding the start and including the end. (Though actually it's a set-subtraction!)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `git rebase` with `--onto`.  This is still a bit tricky, so to make it easy you will want to do one thing different, earlier.

I think it's better, by the way, to draw these graphs with the branch names at the *right* side, pointing to one specific commit.  This is because in Git, commits are on *multiple branches*, and branch names really *do* just point to one specific commit.  It's also worth reversing the internal arrows (because Git really stores them that way) or just using connecting lines so as not to imply the wrong direction.

Hence:

```
          D--E--F   <-- branch2
         /    
  A--B--C       <-- branch1
 /
M          <-- master
```

Commits `A` through `C` really are on both `branch1` *and* `branch2`, while commits `D` through `F` are *only* on `branch2`.  (Commits `M` and earlier are on all three branches.)

What `git rebase upstream` does is select all<sup>1</sup> commits *reachable from* the current branch, but *not reachable from* the *`upstream`* argument, then copy them (with `git cherry-pick` or equivalent) so that they come right after the *`upstream`* commit.

After the squash-"merge" (not really a merge), if you run `git fetch` and then fast-forward your `master`, you have the same thing you drew, but I leave `branch1` in and put the labels on the left and add `origin/master` here:

```
          D--E--F   <-- branch2
         /    
  A--B--C       <-- branch1
 /
M--S       <-- master, origin/master
```

(Or, if you don't fast-forward your `master` yet, only `origin/master` points to commit `S`).

You now want to tell Git to copy `D-E-F` with cherry-pick, then move the label `branch2` to point to the last commit copied.  You *don't* want to copy `A-B-C` as they're incorporated in `S`.  You want the copies to go after `S`, to which `origin/master` now points—whether or not you've updated `master`.  Hence:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase --onto origin/master branch1
```

The *`upstream`* is now `branch1` instead of `master`, but the `--onto` tells Git where to place the copies: `branch1` is only serving to delimit what *not to copy*.  So now Git copies `D-E-F` and changes `branch2` to point there:

```
          D--E--F   [abandoned]
         /    
  A--B--C       <-- branch1
 /
M--S       <-- master?, origin/master
    \
     D'-E'-F'   <-- branch2
```

and *now* you can delete the name `branch1`.  (And now you can fast-forward `master` if you didn't yet—it does not really matter when you do it, and in fact you don't need your own `master` at all.)

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, rebase selects commits that are (a) not merge commits and (b) do not have the same `git patch-id` as some commit in the excluded set, using a symmetric difference.  That is, rather than `upstream..HEAD`, Git actually runs `git rev-list` on `upstream...HEAD`, with `--cherry-mark` or similar, to pick out commits.  The implementations vary slightly depending on the particular kind of rebase.

Comment: Thanks for the great diagrams, I hadn't heard of `--onto` before and it does exactly what I want. I noticed that I got different commit SHAs using `git rebase --onto master branch`` than when I used `git reset --hard master && git cherry-pick branch1..branch2`. Is this doing something fundamentally different than a series of cherry-picks?

Comment: A non-interactive `git rebase` will often pipe `git format-patch` to `git am` to make the commits, but the effect is mostly the same. Commits made at least one second apart will get different hashes (unless carefully controlled, as by, e.g., `git filter-branch`) as they get the 1 second resolution time-stamp of "now" recorded and is part of the data being hashed.